# NSNotificationCenter causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS error with SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, nsnotificationcenter

I'm am using a NSNotificationCenter in an attempt to control a timer in a SpriteKit. The code runs fine when I first enter the SKScene but when I try and re-enter the SKScene I'm getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. I think that this is related to the removeObserver function. I'm not sure when to remove the observer, I tried to do it in the prepareForSegue function with no success. My viewController is as follows:

```
class JobStartedViewController: UIViewController {



var titleOfJob: String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let skView = self.view as! SKView

  let scene:SKScene = GameScene.init(size: skView.bounds.size)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("stopTimerNotification", object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("startTimerNotification", object: nil)

    /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

    /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

    skView.presentScene(scene)
}
```

and I add my observers to my GameScene.swift as follows:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {   


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {


    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "stopTimerInBackground:", name:"stopTimerNotification", object: nil)
     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "startTimerInBackground:", name:"startTimerNotification", object: nil)
```

Comment: You need to remove the observers in your `deinit`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the likely flow of events:

1. You present `JobStartedViewController`, it creates the scene and adds it to the view, triggering `didMoveToView(_:)` and addition of two observers.
2. You dismiss the view controller or remove the scene from the `SKView`.  At some point shortly after, there are no more strong references to the scene and it gets deallocated.  **At this point there are still unsafe references to it in the notification center.**
3. You present another `JobStartedViewController` or otherwise post the `stopTimerNotification` notification.
4. `NSNotificationCenter` tries performing the selector on the deallocated scene and crashes your app.

The normal practice when using `NSNotificationCenter` is to remove your observer in the `dealloc` method for Objective-C or the `deinit` method for Swift:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    // ...

    deinit {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    }
}
```

If you are planning to add and remove that scene from your view multiple times you should also consider removing your observers in `willMoveFromView(_:)`.